# How to get all conflicts together while rebasing?

Tags: git, version-control, rebase, git-merge-conflict

I have been working on my feature branch and I have 10 commits on it. I raised an MR when I was done but the repo always does `git rebase master` before the MR is merged.

So, now when I try to run the rebase from master, each of these 10 commits get placed on top **one by one and I keep getting conflicts for each of them.**

Now, I want a way where I can "collect" all of these commits together and just get one final list of **all conflicts for the sum total changes brought in by  all these 10 commits**.

Note: squashing is not an option as I won't be able to "unsquash" when I am done.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

What you can do, however, is to enable [git rerere](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere): `git config rerere.enabled true`. It stores the conflict resolution and when a similar conflict rises it will try to reuse the recorded resolution.

Comment: but the resolution strategy when commits come in one by one is not the same as when all commits are together, right?

Comment: @DebanikDawn: the *strategy* is the same, if you're referring to the process by which you examine a conflict and resolve it. The *set of conflicts* may differ. But if you get the same conflict over and over, `rerere` will notice that the second time it occurs, it has the same inputs, and will produce the same output.